# Linear independence: span of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a linear independence problem that is confusing me a bit:

"If U is orthogonal to both V and W, and U does not equal zero, argue that U is not in the span of V and W."

I have been attempting to write an argument where I assume that U is in the span, and then prove that it is not using the dot product, but I've got stuck. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are $V,W,U$ all vectors?

Answer (score 1):

If $U$ is in the span of $V$ and $W$ we can write $U=aV+bW$ for some scalars $a$ and $b$. So $ \langle U, U \rangle=\langle U, (aV+bW) \rangle=a\langle U, V \rangle+b\langle U, W \rangle =0$ so $U=0$.

Comment: so would that mean that in this case, a contradiction occurs (U = 0), so we can conclude that U cannot be in the span of V and W?

Comment: @vintage_birdy Yes, that is what I meant.